# Display image from external location by jsf

Tags: jsf, tomcat

I read number of posts about the same issue and the solution from the "tomcat server" side is to add  element inside  element and what i did like this :

```
<Host>
    <Context docBase="path_to_image" path="/images" />
.....
```

My issue now is that if i tried to display the image by html image tag like that :

```
<img src="/images/dist/image_name.ext"/>
```

the image rendered without any problem , but i have aproblem when use the jsf tag like :

```
<h:graphicImage value="/images/dist/image_name.ext" />
```

this tag's output is : [http://localhost:8080/context_name/faces/images/dist/image_name.ext]

so i think if i can point to  [http://localhost:8080/images/dist/image_name.ext] from the jsf component it will solve the issue but how can i make this ?

Any idea ?

I see this article http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html

but it will be betterif i can solve that issue by the server.xml as i mentioned  before .

Answer (score 2):

The `<h:graphicImage>` will indeed implicitly prepend the webapp context path to image's URL. Just don't use it and stick to plain HTML `<img>` element. Whatever reason you've in mind which would require it to be a `<h:graphicImage>` component needs to be reconsidered or solved differently so that you can keep using plain HTML `<img>`. element.

Comment: thank you for your reply .

So if i use servlet "as per your article" will it work ?

thanks again ..

Comment: I didn't answered that you should use it. I just answered that you should keep using `<img>`.