# h:graphicimage value attribute: how to get path of server rather than webapp context root

Tags: jsf, java-ee-7, contextpath

I have configured wildfly to serve images from a certain context like this...

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.0">
       <server name="default-server">
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                 <location name="/images" handler="book-images"/>
                 <!-- More config-->
            </host>
            <!-- More config-->
       </server>
       <handlers>
            <file name="book-images" path="/path/to/book/images" 
                  directory-listing="true"/>
            <!-- More config-->
       </handlers>
       <!-- More config-->
  </subsystem>
```

essentially, this makes it possible to access the files from wildfly at `localhost:8080/images`

i can access the images from the browser without a hitch e.g  `localhost:8080/images/009.jpg`.

what i want is to be able to use these images in from a web app in `img` tags i.e

```
     <h:graphicImage value="/images/#{bookid}.jpg" />
```

but h:graphicimage adds the webapp context root so that `src` tags becomes `/myapp/images/009.jpg`.

my question is, how do i get the path of the server itself so that i can add `/images/` to it and resolve the correct path? or how do i avoid the context root of the web app from being prepended to the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got an answer from BalusC fro another question (stick to plain img). [check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15679607/1788917)